# Spring Integration flow not invoked from handle

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have the following 2 components which should delete first a document from Mongo and afterwards from Elastic.

Main flow:

```
@Component
public class DeleteDocumentFlow {

    @Autowired
    private StoreInMongoFlow storeInMongoFlow;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow deleteDocument() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Channels.METADATA_DELETE_STATUS.name())
                .handle(storeInMongoFlow.deleteDocumentInMongo())
                .channel("deleteDocumentInES.input")
                .get();
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Component
public class StoreInMongoFlow {
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow deleteDocumentInMongo() {
        return flow -> flow.
                <Metadata>handle((p, h) -> {
                    DBObject obj = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("i", p.getId()).get();
                    DeleteResult documentEntry = this.mongoTemplate.remove(obj, "docs");
                    return documentEntry.getDeletedCount();
                })
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO, m -> "Number of documents deleted: " + m.getPayload());
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the *deleteDocumentInMongo* is never invoked. The bean is properly registered as I can see it in the logs.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong or would you need some more debugging info? If I wiretap the handle, then the *deleteDocumentInES.input* is executed but the mongo flow is simply ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely do something fundamentally wrong. You try to treat an `IntegrationFlow` as a service to call from the `handle()`. This is no for what an `IntegrationFlow` has been designed. See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl

> The DSL provides an `IntegrationFlow` component to define a composition of channels and endpoints between them, but now `IntegrationFlow` plays only the configuration role to populate real beans in the application context and is not used at runtime.

if you declare a logic as a separate `IntegrationFlow`, you don't need to worry about that `handle()` - just use `channel("deleteDocumentInMongo.input")` to send a message from point of main flow to a first channel of that MongoDB sub-flow.

If you want to do the same operation with Elastic, you should think about having a `PublishSubscribeChannel` to send a message and two flows starting from this channel.

Since you end `deleteDocumentInMongo` flow with `log()` you can't get any reply back and your  `.channel("deleteDocumentInES.input")` is not going to be reachable.

Please, read more docs to understand what is pub-sub, request-reply, service activator, and flow per se.